# How to navigate a page into another view controller using tableview did select method

Tags: swift3

This is my code to navigate from one viewController to another viewControler but i can't navigate. data is rest api nsobject data that stored category from rest api as name, entertainment is a category . when i tap on category goto another viewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    print("hello welcome on this news page")

    // dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if data[indexPath.row].name == "Entertainment"
    {
         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
         let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WhiteViewController") as! FourthViewController
         navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
         dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
         print("Welcome on Business..!")
    }
}
```

Comment: remove this line of code

  dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: i need to close slide menu on did select method when click on row @IBAction func CloseSlideMenu(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: is there any navigationController  embedded in your storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard use this -

```
if let navigationObject = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboard_name", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcontroller_storyboardId") as? viewController_name {

   navigationController?.pushViewController(navigationObject, animated: true)
            }
```

[image: You should add this first]

Comment: thank u for your suggestion..! but i have use storyboard ID . this is image of my storyboard ID https://prnt.sc/k0qh6b

Answer (score 0):

There could be come following reasons

1. Check if name contains entertainment Or Entertainment as string
   value? means case sensitivity(as a test do following and check)
   data[indexPath.row].name.lowerCased() == "Entertainment".lowerCased()
2. Missing navigationController (navigation controller not embedded) if missing embed
   navigationController to your root controller.
3. try removing `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use This,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if data[indexPath.row].name == "Entertainment" {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let whiteVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WhiteViewController") as! WhiteViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(whiteVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```